# Admin Grid is Showing Wrong filter count Magento 2.4.2

Tags: admin, grid, filter, magento2.4.2, product-grid

I had updated the magento version 2.3.5 to 2.4.2, in the admin when i tried to search the configurable product alone it shows the wrong product count.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default issue in M2.4.2. A patch (**MDVA-36615**) is available for this issue in Commerce Edition, check [here](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060056751-MDVA-36615-catalog-products-grid-filter-incorrect-results)

To resolve it in community edition create preference for

`Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection` and override the `getSize()` method with below code

```
 /**
 * @return int
 */
public function getSize()
{
    return parent::getSize();
}
```

Override in your custom module

Create `di.xml`

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection"/>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductCollection.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return parent::getSize();
    }
}
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32180#issuecomment-825449017) thread for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Patch is available for commerce edition

Comment: Yes tried this it shows the undefied AbstractDb

Comment: Can you share what code you are trying in preference?

Comment: No, For testing i had checking in the vendor files.

Comment: @Sabareesh I've upated my answer please check.

Comment: @Raghul Barot the code is worked, can you give solution using preferences. It is worked thanks :)

Comment: @Sabareesh check updated answer.

Comment: @Sabareesh Can you please accept as solution.